# How to transfer current wallet to another

Tags: ethminer

So I started trying to mine ethereum in one of my spare machines at home. I was able to download and install both geth and ethminer and they are running quietly in the background while I work.

From there, how can I transfer the ether that I mine to another wallet? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send Ether from one account to another, you can use a number of tools.

- [Mist](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases)
- [MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.com)
- [EthTools.com](https://ethtools.com) (Disclosure - this is my product)

These tools allow you to upload or input your private key (with which the transactions will be signed), and then input the transaction details (amount etc) through a simple user interface.

Remember.. your private key is what secures the Ether in your account. You should only input it into well respected sites. Be especially wary of phishing scams whereby scammers use similar (but not correct) urls and pretend to be well known services.

Answer (score 0):

you have two options

First send them from your mining node to your other's wallet address.
Second backup your private keys by backuping your keystore located under :

```
For Linux ~/.ethereum/keystore 
For Windows %appdata%/.ethereum/keystore
```

copy the files you will find there and past them under the same location in your other distant installations.

[image]